# Ruby class design - should I create constants in a seperate file?

Tags: ruby, bunny

I'm new to Ruby, using Bunny to consume messages from RabbitMQ.

So my class currently looks roughly like this:

```
class Consumer

  include Validator

  def initialize
    #Start a RabbitMQ session
    @rdSession = Session.new

    @queueMain = rdSession.joinQueue('QueueMain')
    @queueLittle = rdSession.joinQueue('QueueLittle')
    ...
    @queueTen = rdSession.joinQueue('QueueTen')

    goWork
  end

  def goWork
     @queueMain.subscribe(:manual_ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
        goDoSomethingElse(payload)
      end
     ....
     @queueTen.subscribe(:manual_ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
        goDoAnotherPiece(payload)
      end
  end
```

My question is the file is becoming quite long so I want to reduce it somehow. So one thing I thought of is as those moving that long list of joining queues in `initialize` into another file as they are constant.

However what is the correct way to do this, should I create a module, copy across all those `joinQueue` lines, then refer to them in `goWork` as constants like: `QUEUEMAIN`?

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Trying to understand good design for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more you can refactor here but basically yes you move the lifting to a module and thanks to @Amadan, you can

```
module GoWork
  def goWork
    @queues[:QueMain].subscribe(:manual_ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
      goDoSomethingElse(payload)
    end
    @queues[:QueTen].subscribe(:manual_ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
      goDoAnotherPiece(payload)
    end
  end
end

class Consumer

  include Validator
  include GoWork

  QUEUE_NAMES = %w(QueueMain QueueLittle QueueTen) 

  def initialize
    #Start a RabbitMQ session
    @rdSession = Session.new
    @queues = QUEUE_NAMES.map { |name| [name.to_sym, rdSession.joinQueue(name)] }.to_h

    goWork
  end
end
```

Also see [ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide) it is recommended to user `snake_case` for all method and variable names and to use `CamelCase` for class and module definitions, but I didn't do that as that was not your question.  It is also recommend to use [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) to help keep proper style in mind.

Comment: Thanks - so I was actually thinking moving the `@queueMain = rdSession.joinQueue('QueueMain')` bits into a module. Any other refactor suggestions you have?

Comment: Regarding "that long list of joining queues", I'd probably have `QUEUE_NAMES = %w(QueueMain QueueLittle QueueTen)` and `@queues = QUEUE_NAMES.map { |name| [name.to_sym, rdSession.joinQueue(name) }` - no need for each of them to get their own instance variable. This renames `@queueMain` to `@queues[:QueueMain]`.